# How to implement multiple buttons on Onitemclicklistener function interface?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, android-music-player

I am not understanding here how to use this interface `OnItemClickListener` for multiple buttons

```
package com.mtechviral.musicplayer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SongAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongAdapter.SongHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SongInfo> _songs = new ArrayList<SongInfo>();
    private Context context;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    public SongAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SongInfo> songs) {
        this.context = context;
        this._songs = songs;
    }

    //getting a error
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Button b ,View view, SongInfo obj, int position);
        //add another button parameter
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Button bt ,View view, SongInfo obj, int position);
        //add another button parameter
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public SongHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View myView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_songs,viewGroup,false);
        return new SongHolder(myView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SongHolder songHolder, final int i) {
            final SongInfo s = _songs.get(i);
            songHolder.tvSongName.setText(_songs.get(i).getSongname());
            songHolder.tvSongArtist.setText(_songs.get(i).getArtistname());
            songHolder.btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                        mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(songHolder.btnAction,v, s, i);
                    }
                }
            });
        songHolder.btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                    mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(songHolder.btnStop,v, s, i);
                }
            }
        });

        //write a function for pause
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return _songs.size();
    }

    public class SongHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvSongName,tvSongArtist;
        Button btnAction,btnStop;

        //declare a new button............................................
        public SongHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvSongName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSongName);
            tvSongArtist = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvArtistName);
            btnAction = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAction);
            btnStop = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
            //declaraion details
            //....................................................
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't copy/paste the same sentence over and over just to meet the requirements. Instead, explain the problem in more detail and show only the relevant code. And when you post the relevant code, format it first to remove all the unnecessary whitespace.

Comment: do a research first before jumping here

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define multiple interfaces for handling the multiple buttons. You can use only one method or you can add another method inside the listener interface to handle both the click. In my perspective, you should add another method to separate the handling. Something like this:

```
public class SongAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongAdapter.SongHolder> {

  ...

  public interface OnItemClickListener {
    // Only use 2 parameters because you just need them.
    void onActionClicked(SongInfo obj, int position);
    void onStopClicked(SongInfo obj, int position);
  }

  public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
    this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
  }

  ...

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final SongHolder songHolder, final int i) {
    ...

    songHolder.btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
          mOnItemClickListener.onActionClicked(s, i);
        }
      }
    });

    songHolder.btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
          mOnItemClickListener.onStopClicked(s, i);
        }
      }
    });

    //write a function for pause
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: can u elaborate plz

Comment: can u elaborate plz

Comment: `but i hv to capture tet written on button and the give its function accordingly ` I can't grasp what your intent here. What did you want to do with the button?

Comment: thank u..... i understood