# Android Image button Dial / call from a custom list view Error with NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

In my listview I added a button with icon/image and try to make a call from that button with the string number from the listview. but somehow its not working or show me error

[image]

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference at com.rupom.sss.EmployeeContactList.onCreate
```

**Here is my java code**

```
public class EmployeeContactList  extends Activity {


    public EmployeeContactList(){}
    ListView empList;

    String[] EmpName = {
            "ROB","Fredrik","Mihai","Andru","Gob shafin","Andru","Gob shafin","Andru","Gob shafin","Andru","Gob shafin","Andru","Gob shafin"

    };
    String[] EmpDeg = {
            "Senior Officer","Junior Officer","Officer","Junior Officer","Officer","Junior Officer","Officer","Junior Officer","Officer","Junior Officer","Officer","Junior Officer","Officer"

    };
    String[] EmpMobile = {
            "1245454544552","12345678912","12345678912","12345678912","12345678912","12345678912","12345678912","12345678912","12345678912","12345678912","12345678912","12345678912","12345678912"
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_employee_list);
        empList = findViewById(R.id.employeelistView);

        CustomEmployeeListAdapter customEmployeeListAdapter = new CustomEmployeeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), EmpName, EmpDeg,EmpMobile);
        empList.setAdapter(customEmployeeListAdapter);

    }


}
```

**Custom list adapter**

```
public class CustomEmployeeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    String[] EmpName;
    String[] EmpDeg;
    String[] EmpMobile;


    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomEmployeeListAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] EmpName, String[] EmpDeg, String[] EmpMobile) {
        this.context = context;
        this.EmpName = EmpName;
        this.EmpDeg = EmpDeg;
        this.EmpMobile = EmpMobile;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return EmpName.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return EmpName[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        String text = (String) getItem(position);
        //get the layout
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.list_employee, null);
        //get the fields of list view
        TextView tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.employee_name);
        TextView tvDeg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_sub_emp_deg);
        TextView tvMobile = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_sub_emp_mobile);



        //set value from string
        tvName.setText(EmpName[position]);
        tvDeg.setText(EmpDeg[position]);
        tvMobile.setText(EmpMobile[position]);


        final TextView mobNumber = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_sub_emp_mobile);
        final ImageView empCall = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.empCallBtn);
        final String mobile_number = mobNumber.getText().toString();
        // Click listener of button
        empCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+mobile_number));
                //context.startActivity(callIntent);
                Log.i("PHONENUMBER","Clicked !!!!!!! "+ mobile_number);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: This line get error -   String uri = "tel:" + mobNumber.getText().toString(); you have to print uri and check it.

Comment: yes i think so but the list was working fine before adding call action

Comment: try to print String uri in log.

Comment: `empCall` seems to be `null` so this call is producing the error: `empCall.setOnClickListener(...)`

Comment: @Chris623 I have added an image of how it looks before call function added Also Added my Custom list adapter

Comment: @Shane I have found an issue on `CustomEmployeeListAdapter` where  ` getItem` set to null and don't know how to fix that  
`public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }`

Comment: You're current error: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'` means that you don't correctly bind the ImageButton or there is no ImageButton with the specific id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the correct value for all of your BaseAdapter methods. So, update your code to something like this:

```
public class CustomEmployeeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    String[] EmpName;
    String[] EmpDeg;
    String[] EmpMobile;

    ...

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return EmpName[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    ...

}
```

---

**For improvement:**

You better to use a pojo which include all of your Employee information. For example, you can use `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee {
  private String name;
  private String degree;
  private String mobile;

  // constructor
  // setter
  // getter

}
```

then, you can use it in your adapter:

```
public class CustomEmployeeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<Employee> mEmployees;

    ...

    public CustomEmployeeListAdapter(Context ctx, List<Employee> employees) {
        this.context = ctx;
        mEmployees employees;

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mEmployees.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mEmployees.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        //get the layout
        ...

        Employee employee = (Employee) getItem(position);

        tvName.setText(employee.getName());
        tvDeg.setText(employee.getDegree());
        tvMobile.setText(employee.getMobile());

        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you see my `CustomEmployeeListAdapter ` I update my code and now a issue when click I can see the correct log text but failed call new activity from outside an activity

Comment: Please check your `R.id.empCallBtn` in your item layout. Did you have the id in it?

Comment: `       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/empCallBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/call_button_green" />`

Comment: Now it return the correct number I can see on `Log` after moving my on click listener from activity to my adapter but failed to start Activity from outside an Activity `CustomEmployeeListAdapter`

Comment: You shouldn't start activity inside the Adapter. You need to delegate it via Callback/Listener mechanism.

Comment: I am very new at android developing So can you show me an example. I Know your method is good but its hard for me to recode everything :(

Comment: @Firefog: You don't need to re-code everything, just learn it first until you're familiarize yourself with it. For Callback mechanism, you can see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46985757/4758255

Comment: If you've solved the previous problem, please close this by creating an answer then accept it. Or you can mark my answer as accepted answer.

Comment: Yes i applied your method